# Create a C++ empty project on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a C++ empty project on Visual Studio 2017 ,but the files( External Dependencies, Header Files, Resources Files, Source Files) are not created.

1. **File->New->Project**
2. I choose **Empty Project**

[image: Here is the problem]

Comment: You created an empty project. It is empty. What did you expect?

Comment: Project node in Solution Explorer is actually collapsed...

Comment: when i add an item ,it doesn't appeared in Resourses View

Answer (score 0):

That's why it's Called **EMPTY PROJECT**.
and Your "Project1" node is collapsed.

to Add a .cpp or .h file : Right Click on **Project1** in Solution explorer --> add item --> Then chose a file type and give it a name.

Comment: when i add an item ,it doesn't appeared in Resourses View

Comment: Hi, Please Make sure Your "Project1" node is not collapsed,